# Index list reference within a string

Tags: python, sql, string, indexing

I'm looking to automate a sql query. My thought is to leverage index reference (and maybe this is possible to do all in sql but am unsure).

I realize that I can use {} to reference a variable, but how to reference a list like cols = ['col1','col2']?

I have a sql query within jupyter notebook that is read in as a string like this -

```
"""
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN col1 is null AND col2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS combo
FROM mytable
"""
```

But I'd like to run a function with parameter replace where the sql looks something like this -

```
"""
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN cols[0] is null AND cols[1] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS combo
FROM mytable
"""
```

And columns are an input

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
```

Appreciate any guidance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Is the data already stored as JSON or an array?

Comment: my goal is only to get the column name for reference in the sql query. wouldn't matter what db but not JSON it is an array